# Why can low priority processes affect the latency of an high priority process?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, scheduling

I have tested the rt process's latency by cyclictest. And found that when I launch a few lower priority rt processes(priority is 40) the high priority rt process's latency will get bigger. I can't explain this.

cyclictest is one of the programs of rt-tests.
https://github.com/jlelli/rt-tests/tree/master/src/cyclictest

Cyclictest measures the latency between when a
timer expires and when the thread which set the timer actually
runs. It does this by taking a time snapshot just prior to waiting for
a specific time interval (t1), then taking another time snapshot after
the timer finishes (t2), then comparing the theoretical wakeup time
with the actual wakeup time (t2 -(t1 + sleep_time)). This value is the
latency for that timer wakeup.

The cyclictest's fake code:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t1);
next = t1 + 1000;
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &next, NULL);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t2);
latency = t2 - next;
```

The test command is(-p80 means the test thread's priority is 80, the -n means useing clock_nanosleep to waiting for a specific time interval):
**./cyclictest -p80 -n**

The disturbing process is simple:

```
struct sched_param schedp;
schedp.sched_priority = 40;
sched_set_scheduler(0, SHED_FIFO, &schedp);
while(1) {
    srand(time(0));
    while(j++ < rand()%1000000);
    usleep(10);
}
```

In Linux kernel, no matter how many lower priority processes are there, as long as the high priority process is runnable, it will be executed immediately.

Can anyone explain why launching a few low priority processes can affect high priority process's latency?

Comment: Show the code of your rt process and how you measure latency, as well as complete code of your `cyclictest` (what is `-p80` and `-n`?).

Comment: Also should show your kernel `.config`. There are various tickless/hrtimer options that need to be right for realtime to behave even remotely correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. At first, I would ensure more RT-ability by applying the Preempt_RT patch to your Linux kernel.
2. Next, if I am right, all timers are controlled by the softIRQ daemon (see `ps -e | grep soft`) which has a low default priority. That's why increase it for your core e.g. by `chrt --fifo --pid 90 9` for cpu 0. Also switch off the disturbing printk as much as you can (e.g. `sysctl kernel.printk='3 3 3 3'`) because it heavily breaks realtime.
3. Third, expired timers run their call with the inherited priority of the task which created the timer. That's why ensure, you use a schedulling mode other than SCHED_OTHER for it (e.g. SCHED_RR or SCHED_FIFO) and set a sufficiently high priority. SCHED_OTHER threads don't have a realtime priority, because for those threads you can just use the nice level which is between Linux kernel priority 20 and -20 AFAIRC.